# Jquery If statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to hide and show a option based on it's class. Can anyone help me see why this isn't working?

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#product_boutique").val( <? echo $rowO->product_boutique ?> );
                $("#product_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category ?>' );
                $("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category ?>' );
                var select = $("#product_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' ).val();

                if (select == 'womenswear'){
                      $('.mens').hide();
                      $('.womens').show();
                }
                if (select == 'menswear'){
                      $('.mens').show();
                      $('.womens').hide();
                }   

            });
```

Comment: Do you know that you can accept an answer when you have the response to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var select = $("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' );
alert(typeof select); // object
```

Because .val('...') returns a jquery object.

Try

```
var select = $("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' ).val();
```

By doing that, you set the value to the #product_sub_category and you retrieve it to variable select.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery `val(value)` method returns a jQuery object, not a string. If you change:

```
var select = $("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' );
```

to:

```
var select = $("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' ).val();
```

it should work fine. Because the `val(value)` method returns a jQuery object, you can chain it with other jQuery methods as I've done above, so 2 calls to `val` in the same line will work fine.

Comment: When I posted this you hadn't edited your answer to show the actual solution, you only had the `alert(typeof select);` part.

Answer (score 2):

When you are passing argument to .val(), as in your case, you are setting the value. To get the current value, you  have to call .val() without arguments.

```
$("#product_sub_category").val( '<? echo $rowO->category; ?>' );
var select = $("#product_sub_category").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
if (select == 'womenswear'){
    $('.mens').hide();
    $('.womens').show();
}
if (select == "menswear"){
    $('.mens').hide();
    $('.womens').show();
}
```

It should be:

```
if (select == 'womenswear'){
    $('.mens').hide();
    $('.womens').show();
}
if (select == "menswear"){
    $('.mens').show();
    $('.womens').hide();
}
```